# Firefox newly created theme (following tutorial) doesn't change anything in the UI

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I started developing a Firefox theme. A real one using the addon engine, not one of those personas.

## The problem

I followed [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Building_a_Theme) (official) tutorial step by step. However no matter what I'm trying to do the UI of Firefox doesn't change a bit. Could it be that it is outdated? Just for the record. I exactly did the things I'll describe below. If you trust me that I didn't miss anything in the tutorial you can straightly go to point 6.

## What I did

1. I created the files `install.rdf` and `chrome.manifest` in my empty theme folder. The content of `install.rdf` is exactly like in the tutorial except that I changed `sample@example.net` to `[UID]@example.net` where `[UID]` is a unique ID that I got from [this site](https://www.famkruithof.net/uuid/uuidgen). I also changed `maxVersion` to `49.*` and replaced name, description, creator, ... ✓
2. I copy-pasted the contents of `chrome.manifest` from the tutorial to my file ✓
3. I extracted the files `/usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja` and `/usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja`. Furthermore I copied the folders `browser/`, `communicator/`, `global/` and `mozapps/` from the extracted data to the subfolder `chrome` just like in the tutorial. ✓
4. I changed a CSS rule in `themeName/chrome/browser/browser.css` (`background-color` in `#navigator-toolbox` from `transparent` to `orange` to be exact) and saved the file. ✓
5. I created a new 'dev' profile by executing `firefox -no-remote -P dev`, then opened the Root Directory of the newly created "dev" profile via `about:profile` and closed firefox after that. In the profile I created a new text file under the directory `extensions` with "[UID]@example.net" as its name. The content of the file points to the theme directory (no trailing spaces) ✓
6. I started firefox using the "dev" profile again. It opened a new tab and asked if I would allow to install my new theme. (It even showed the right name that I have given it.) I ticked yes and clicked continue. After that I enabled it in the addons/themes section and restarted.  ✓

## Result

The UI didn't change. I tried this with different CSS rules. However none of these changes worked. Moreover if I go to `chrome://browser/content/browser.xul` and inspect the CSS rules I can see that none of the rules got changed. They have all the same value as in the original CSS file.

I even generated a .xpi file that I successfully installed. But it didn't change anything either. The CSS that the inspector shows for `browser.xul` always mismatches the `browser.css` file from the .xpi.

## Additional

There are no errors in the `browser.css` file. I double checked that. After all I just altered one or two values.
I'm using Firefox 49.0. I don't think that it matters, but I'm working under Arch Linux. Unfortunately my google search was not fruitful at all. If there's anything to add that I don't know about write it in the comments.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Quote From MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Building_a_Theme#Create_a_Chrome_Manifest)

> The third column needs to match your theme's internalName value from the install manifest above.

**From my question**

> I copy-pasted the contents of `chrome.manifest` from the tutorial to my file

So the part that I got wrong was not to replace `sample` with the `internalName` that I defined in the `install.rdf`. After I corrected that one the hello world theme finally works.